# Calculate the acceleration of a superman in running shoes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

> The friction coefficient between an athlete's shoes and the ground is $0.90$. Suppose a superman wears these shoes and races for $50 m$. There is no upper limit on his capacity of running at high speeds. a) Find the minimum time that he will have to take to complete the $50 m$ starting from rest. b) Suppose he takes exactly this minimum time to complete the $50 m$. What time will he take to stop?

My textbook goes out and assumes the superman's maximum acceleration to be $a$. Then, the author reasons, the force on his body should be exactly $\mu R$, where $R$ is the normal force and $\mu$ is the friction coefficient. Then,
$$ma = \mu R$$
$$\rightarrow ma =\mu mg$$
$$\rightarrow a = \mu g$$
Since the values of $\mu$ and $g$ are known, we can find out $a$ to further solve the problem.

In the superman's case, his maximum acceleration seems to depend only on the friction coefficient of his running shoes. How would the situation be different for a non-superman?

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the force propelling the (super)man forwards is a Newtonian reaction force from the (super)man pushing backwards on the ground. By Newton's third law, the force pushing forwards on the runner is equal to the force pushing backwards.

A normal human is unable to exert so much force on the ground that their good-quality trainers slip (try it), so their speed is limited by the strength of their muscles, not by the coefficient of friction. Superman, it is presumed, can exert arbitrarily strong force, so there is something else limiting his speed.

This effect is the reason why top track sprinters wear special shoes with spikes in them: they exert so much force during their acceleration that in normal shoes there may be a risk of slipping.